# Replacing (multiple things) before a certain character

Tags: vba, excel, replace

I have a two sheets. On the first is a column with things such as "one", "one + two", "onetwo + three" etc. On the second are two columns, the first having the "find" part and the second having the "replace" part (e.g. "one" in column A and "1" in column B)

I would like to do a find and replace using a macro such that it only replaces things found before the "+" character, using the replacement keys from the second sheet. I want to get "1", "1 + two", "12 + three" as the result.

I'm currently using this which i found somewhere else

```
    Sub multiFindandReplace()

    Dim myList As Range, myRange As Range, cel As Range

    Set myList = Sheets("sheet2").Range("A1:B20")     'two column range with find/replace pairs
    Set myRange = Sheets("sheet1").Range("A1:A20") 'range to be searched and replace
    For Each cel In myList.Columns(1).Cells
        myRange.Replace What:=cel.Value, Replacement:=cel.Offset(0, 1).Value, LookAt:=xlPart
    Next cel

    End Sub
```

which does everything except only affecting the part of the cell before "+".

thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An alternate method could be to store the replacement values to an array and loop through them.

This example splits all the cell texts by `+` into an array, then just runs `Replace` on the first element of the array.

```
Sub ReplaceTest()

Dim replaceRange() As Variant
Dim replaceSht As Worksheet
Dim marker As String
Dim myRange As Range, values As Variant
Dim firstReplacementColumn As Long
Dim replaceEndRow As Long

'this is the sheet that the replacement values are in
Set replaceSht = Sheet1

'first replacement column is "A"
'(so the values to replace will be in the next column "B")
firstReplacementColumn = 1

'range that we want to replace
Set myRange = Sheets("sheet1").Range("E1:E6")

'what we want to match in our string
marker = "+"

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


'get end row of the replacements
replaceEndRow = replaceSht.Cells(replaceSht.Rows.Count, firstReplacementColumn).End(xlUp).Row

'add all the replacements into an array
ReDim replaceRange(1 To replaceEndRow, 1 To 2)
replaceRange = replaceSht.Range(replaceSht.Cells(1, firstReplacementColumn) _
                                , replaceSht.Cells(replaceEndRow, firstReplacementColumn + 1)).Value2


    'cycle through our range of stuff we want to check and replace
    For Each cell In myRange

    'split the values on + to an array
    values = Split(cell.Value, marker)

        'if the value has been split then there must be at least 1 + in the string
        If UBound(values) > 0 Then

            'loop through all the replacement array and replace
            For i = LBound(replaceRange) To UBound(replaceRange)
            'we're only interested in doing replaces before the first + (so just values(0))
            values(0) = Replace(values(0), replaceRange(i, 1), replaceRange(i, 2))
            Next i

        cell.Value = Join(values, marker)

        End If

    Next cell

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

Exit Sub
err:

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

MsgBox err.Description, vbCritical, "An error occured"

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't do anything to cells without a + in them ("one" isn't changing to "1")

Comment: just remove `If UBound(values) > 0 Then` and the corresponding `End If` and it will replace on the first element of the array regardless if there is a `+`